# Suricata, Docker, and host networking: No non-docker traffic

Tags: networking, docker, snort

I've created a docker container with Suricata and Evebox on it. On my host I start with:

```
ifconfig enp2s0:1 192.168.0.111 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

This sets up a new interface off my existing one. I then run the docker container like so:

```
docker run --privileged --network host --cap-add NET_ADMIN --cap-add NET_RAW --rm suricata-evebox
```

I then fire up suricata/evebox with:

```
mkdir -p /data/evebox
suricata -i enp2s0:1 -D
evebox -v -D /data/evebox --datastore sqlite --input /var/log/suricata/eve.json
```

Here are the scenarios when running `curl http://testmyids.com` from machines:

- Inside a docker container: DETECTS ALERT
- On the docker host: DETECTS ALERT
- On a machine on the local network: DOESN'T SEE IT

Is there a way to get Suricata to see all traffic traveling over the network, not just that of the host and the containers?

Comment: Note: I know I could set up the host or a container on the host as a traffic router and then set my DHCP to assign it as the gateway, but looking to see if there are any other solutions that don't require a docker instance to be a failure point for the internal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First here's a possible solution that could either be set up on the router itself or on any machine you'd like monitored: https://superuser.com/questions/853077/iptables-duplicate-traffic-to-another-ip

If that's not possible for your use case, there's another option in the form of a switch that can be set up between your router and all the clients, the switch should support port mirroring. You'd then add another NIC to your ids/docker host which would receive all the traffic from the mirrored switch's "WAN" port, which can be passed through to your suricata container.